# Has New York been repaired to its state before The Avengers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers

In The Avengers, New York got pretty messed up by the Chitauri - the Hulk didn't exactly help limit the damage either.

However, unlike many movies where New York is damaged, the "Battle of New York" is referenced in following movies and in the Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. TV show.

**So has there been any indication that New York has been repaired to a working state prior to "The Battle of New York?**

[image][image]

Comment: Depending on how much money you're willing to spend, you could clean up all of the damage caused within a few weeks.

Comment: @Richard I'm not asking if it could be done, but if it *has* been done. Phase 2 of the MCU all happens after the Battle, so at some point New York would be repair, but has it been?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Probably.  Phase 2 has been happening in real-time, so the 6 month gap between film releases corresponds to ~6 months in universe.  It's been a few years, I'm sure it's been cleaned up, but since we haven't seen NYC, we lack confirmation.

Comment: Well, I just looked out my office window and it all seems cleaned up.  :p

Comment: @Chahk - you clearly don't work on [7th Ave and 47d st](http://newyork.cbslocal.com/2014/08/05/multiple-injuries-reported-after-2-double-decker-buses-collide-in-times-square/)

Comment: @Chahk- Well, *relatively* cleaned, I imagine.

Comment: If I remember correctly they mention rebuilding New York in Winter Soldier or Thor. I don't remember about Ironman 3, but Stark Tower looked okay.  Time for a rewatch for an answer.  There may also be hints in Agents of Shield, but I am not caught up.

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest Oh gosh, I forgot about that. They did a fly by shot of New York during the "target scanning" scene, and showed Stark Tower and most of New York not being a broken mess!

Comment: In the new Daredevil series there have been some mentions of ongoing reconstruction in New York

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although yet to explicitly stated, as of Captain America: The Winter Soldier much of New York appears to have been repaired. During the finale

> when the Hydra operated helicarriers are targeting civilians,

there is a brief satellite shot of a repaired Avengers tower, which was at ground zero of the Chitauri invasion of New York. The surrounding area was relatively well maintained, or at least showed no signs of the corpses of the 2 or 3 behemoths the Avengers brought down.

Comment: Given the events of the One-Shot films, and the episodes of Agents of SHIELD dealing with citizens finding/stealing weapons/artifacts from the Battle of NY, it seems SHIELD has either largely cleaned up or otherwise contained ground zero.

Answer (score 8):

New information has surfaced that casts new light on this question:

### No, the repairs are ongoing as of 2015

A large portion of the plot of Season 1 of the Netflix *Daredevil* TV show (released Spring 2015) revolves around construction companies getting contracts for continued rebuilding after the Battle of New York, and the repercussions of those shifts of money and power.  I wrote a [fairly long answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86432/20221) to another question detailing why the repairs would take this long, and comparing it to other real-world citywide disasters.

For what it's worth, I imagine we'll get a bit more information about repairs when *Avengers: Age of Ultron* comes out, as it pertains to the rebuilt Stark/Avengers Tower.

Comment: There's [a lot of discussion of when DD takes place](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86430/5184), and a number of signs point to it starting in 2014.

Comment: @phantom42 You know you just linked me to the same question I linked to in my answer, right?  And that mine is the highest-rated answer in that question?  :P  Yeah, maybe a part of Daredevil is 2014, but Brennan's answer proves that by Ep8 it's Sept 2015.  So regardless of when Daredevil starts, the repairs are clearly ongoing at least into 2015.